# Change CodenameOne InfiniteContainer PullToRefresh Behaviour

Tags: codenameone

Can I change pulltorefresh behaviour in CodenameOne InfiniteContainer, to for example execute my code in this event?  JB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `InfiniteContainer` just override the [refresh()](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/InfiniteContainer.html#refresh--) method and write in your own functionality.